# Please spot the error in this merge sort code

Tags: sorting, mergesort

I have provided the code for sorting an array using the merge sort algorithm, I'm unable to find the error, this code is not giving the correctly sorted array as it's output. The function `mergesort` is called recursively to divide the array till its size is reduced to 1. Then multiple arrays are merged using the `merge` function.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void merge(int a[], int m, int l, int h) {
    int n1 = m - l + 1, n2 = h - m;
    int t1[n1], t2[n2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        t1[i] = a[i + l];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        t2[i] = a[i + m + 1];
    }
    int k = 0, p = 0, r = 0;
    while (k < n1 && p < n2) {
        if (t1[k] <= t2[p]) {
            a[r] = t1[k];
            k++;
            r++;
        } else {
            a[r] = t2[p];
            p++;
            r++;
        }
    }
    while (k < n1) {
        a[r] = t1[k];
        k++;
        r++;
    }
    while (p < n2) {
        a[r] = t2[p];
        p++;
        r++;
    }
}

void mergesort(int a[], int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int m = l + (h - l) / 2;
        mergesort(a, l, m);
        mergesort(a, m + 1, h);
        merge(a, m, l, h);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    mergesort(a, 0, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using descriptive variables names would make the code a lot less confusing and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in the `merge` function is `r` should be initialized to `l`, not `0`. You are not merging the slices into the original position.

Also note that the last loop `while (p < n2)` in this function is redundant: the remaining elements in the right slice are already in the proper place in the original array.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
void merge(int a[], int m, int l, int h) {
    int n1 = m - l + 1, n2 = h - m;
    int t1[n1], t2[n2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        t1[i] = a[i + l];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        t2[i] = a[i + m + 1];
    }
    int k = 0, p = 0, r = l;
    while (k < n1 && p < n2) {
        if (t1[k] <= t2[p]) {
            a[r] = t1[k];
            k++;
            r++;
        } else {
            a[r] = t2[p];
            p++;
            r++;
        }
    }
    while (k < n1) {
        a[r] = t1[k];
        k++;
        r++;
    }
}
```

To further simplify the code, here are some more remarks:

- it is less confusing to make use the convention that `h` be the first index beyond the end of the slice. This way the initial call uses the array length and `mergesort` can compute the slice length as `h - l`.
- variable name `l` looks confusingly close to number `1`.
- the arguments to `merge` are usually in the order `l`, `m`, `h`, and `m` is the index of the start of the right slice.
- the right slice does not need saving.
- using variable length arrays with automatic storage `t1[n2]` may cause a *stack overflow* for large arrays.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void merge(int a[], int lo, int m, int hi) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - lo;
    int t1[n1];
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        t1[i] = a[lo + i];
    }
    i = 0;
    j = m;
    k = lo;
    while (i < n1 && j < hi) {
        if (t1[i] <= a[j]) {
            a[k++] = t1[i++];
        } else {
            a[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        a[k++] = t1[i++];
    }
}

void mergesort(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi - lo >= 2) {
        int m = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        mergesort(a, lo, m);
        mergesort(a, m, hi);
        merge(a, lo, m, hi);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[5] = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 };
    mergesort(a, 0, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```